# Simple C question regarding *

Tags: c, variables, pointers

I was wondering what is the difference between these two lines of code?

```
int hi;
int *hi;
```

In the C programming language?

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: You may want to gain a deeper understanding of pointers: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int hi;
```

reserves the space for an `int` in memory, and each time you reference `hi`, you either read or write directly that `int` in memory space.

```
int *hi;
```

reserves the space for a `pointer` to an `int` in memory, each time `hi` is used, the pointer is either read or written. Meaning that you are *not* working with an `int`, only a pointer to an `int` - there must exist an `int` somewhere for the pointer to reference something workable. For instance

```
 int hi;
 int *phi;
 phi = &hi; // phi references the int hi
 *phi = 3;  // set `hi` to 3
```

Comment: Fantastic. Exactly what I wanted to know. Could I bother you with just one more question? I've seen pointers used very extensively. Why? Why are they so special? Why do some prefer to use pointers rather than just integers?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean integers, meant int variables.

Comment: One more comment, sorry. If I had something like this: `int hi[4]; int *phi; phi = &hi[2];` This would give phi the value of third (assuming 0-index) value of the array of `hi`. Now is it possible to accomlish this without pointers? For ex.: `int hi[4]; int phi; phi = hi[2]; `. Would that not do the same thing? If so, I can now finally see why pointers are useful.

Comment: @Amit Why pointers are used? C and C++ allow that level of indirection (unlike eg Java, at least not directly). Based on your exemple, you could reserve in memory a *string* (array) of integers, and have a pointer point to that area, ie the 1st one. Then the language allows conveniently to navigate in that *string* using the pointer, the post or pre increments etc... Following the same scheme, you could provide a function with just a pointer to the *string* of `int`, instead of providing the whole array. Operations are permitted on pointers etc etc... (try to google "c pointers" for instance).

Comment: @Amit-II `phi=&hi[2];` will set phi to the address of the memory location where the 3rd int of `hi` resides. Then, `*phi=4;` set `hi[2]` to 4. You could do `phi=&hi; *(phi+2)=4;` for the same effect, or even `phi[2]=4;`.

Comment: @ring0: I see. Thanks a lot. I truly appreciate your help and expertise

Answer (score 2):

`int hi` declares the variable hi to be an [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Integers_in_computing).
`int *hi` declares the variable hi to be a [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29) to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The first declares an integer variable, while the second declares a pointer to an integer.

Pointers are beyond the scope of a StackOverflow post, but [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29) is a starting point, and there should be at least a chapter on pointers in whatever book you're using to learn C.

Answer (score 1):

`hi` stores the integer type value in a particular location, but
`*hi` stores the address of any int type variable.

Example :

```
int hi = 10;
int *hello = &hi;
```

Answer (score 0):

a. `int i;`
b. `int *address;`
c. `address = &i;`

In line a an integer variable named `i` is declared. When this is done the compiler reserves a memory space of size `sizeof(int)` (it's 4 byte on my computer). If you want to refer to this memory space then you have to use pointers.

Line b declares a variable named `address` which has a special property. This variable doesn't holds an `int` but it stores the address of a variable that is of type `int`. Therefore, whatever value `address` has, it should be interpreted as the address of a variable which is of type `int`.  Currently, the variable `address` doesn't hold any memory address in it as we haven't yet defined which variable's memory address it has to hold.

Line c can be read as "address is equal to the memory address of variable `i`". Now, the variable address stores the memory address of the `int` variable `i`.

```
int main(){
  int a;
  int &b;
  b=&a;
  a=10;
  return 0;
}
```

When this code is run using a debugger I see:

```
a = 10 // the variable's value  
b = 0x7fffffffe2fc // this is the address at which 'a' is stored.
```

Pointers are very powerful and you will start to use it more often once you understand it. Apart from the materials that others suggested for you to read I suggest use a debugger(gdb) and run a few programs with pointers in it and check every variable that you declared in the code. I understand things better when I have a visual picture of any problem and I think it might as well speed up your understanding of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

int hi------ indicates that hi is the integer which allocates 2 bytes for it.
int *hi------ * indicates the pointer which holds the address of the variable and that variable is an integer.
both are different.one indicates the integer and the other indicates the address of the integer.

Answer (score 0):

int hi;
reserve a place in the memory for an integer variable while 
int *ptr;
reserve a place in the memory for a pointer which contain the memory address of other variable. you can use the pointers in different ways.

```
int *ptr = hi;
int *ptr;
ptr = &hi;
```

when you change the value of the ptr you change the address where it is pointing for but if you changed the value after de-referencing the address you are changing the value of the other variable.

```
*ptr = 3;
```

leads to change the value of hi;

Answer (score 0):

First -**int hi**;
here you declaring a integer variable named "hi"

Then -**int *hi**;
here "hi" is a pointer which can point to a integer value

Note:***int* hi and int *hi***   are syntactically same